# Check For Leading/Trailing Whitespaces

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a function that checks for leading and trailing whitespaces. It shouldn't remove them, just check to see if they exist. I wrote this:

```
  public static String checkWhitespace(String str)
  {
      if(str.charAt(0) == ' ' || str.charAt(str.length()-1) == ' ');
            return "invalid";
  }
```

But it's catching everything. I tried using `"\\s+"` as the key but it's a string and it's only letting me check for chars. Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 17):

You could do

```
return str.trim().equals(str) ? "valid": "invalid";
```

Comment: Nice oneliner (and bad aiming in my hand, I accidentally downvoted :) )

Comment: Fun fact: you could also use `str.trim()==str` because [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) returns "_A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or **this string if it has no leading or trailing white space**._" So reference can be checked for equality instead of value. Would personally still use `.equals` when dealing with Strings though, but thought it was something worth mentioning. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Character.isWhitespace` instead of the "\\s+" regex you suggested.

```
public static String checkWhitespace(String str) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(0)) || Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(str.length() - 1))) {
        return "invalid";
    }
}
```

By the way, the semicolon at the end of the `if` statement might be what's tripping you up. That would cause it to always execute `return "invalid"`.

Comment: Ehem, the `charAt(-1)` doesn't work. You're also not checking for valid indices (`str` may be empty).

Comment: True. I'm not a java programmer, so I wasn't sure what the if the -1 was a valid index on a string. I was mostly just putting `Character.isWhitespace` into the original code so OP could get a better idea.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I copied the code wrong. Been doing too much ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `"\\s+"` does not work is because you need to be using Java's Regex Matcher\Pattern classes to be checking with a regex.

```
String input = "   blah   ";
String regexLeadingWhitespace = "\\s+.*";
String regexTrailingWhitespace = ".*\\s+";

boolean leadingMatches = Pattern.matches(regexLeadingWhitespace, input);
boolean trailingMatches = Pattern.matches(regexTrailingWhitespace, input);
```

Disclaimer: I think my regexes are correct but I could be wrong, I haven't had a chance to test them out yet.

[Java Regex Matacher Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html)